# team explorer 2017 branched code also reflecting the master

Tags: visual-studio-2017, team-explorer

I have a problem in Team Explorer (VS2017) where I branch my code from the master and call it test (for example).
When I made changes in test branch and switched back to master, the changes in the test branch is also showing in master.

I don't understand why this is happening, I only noticing this after I upgraded from VS2015.
I have uninstalled VS2015 and I cannot go back and verify that this is a problem with VS2017.

Is there a settings that I have overlooked in VS2017?

Answer (score 0):

Team Explorer will not automatically merge the test branch back into master (in VS2017 or VS2015), so let's look at your workflow that leads to this result.  Could you please list for me each step you take when starting at the master branch, creating the test branch, committing changes, etc.  If possible, screenshots at each step may help me look for other clues.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think it merges to the master, it simply doesn't switch to the master branch correctly.  I will try and create some screenshots.